# Is saying thank you in this webboard consider as spam ?

Tags: support, spam

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Etiquette on addressing fellow-users](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1121/etiquette-on-addressing-fellow-users)

StackExchange seems to be a serious website that everyone interest on the quality of question and answer, i just want to know that is this webboard considers things like "Thank you" as a spam or not ?

Comment: Please have a look at the link above; it addresses your question.

Comment: A better way to say "thank you" is with an upvote.

Comment: Sometime that comment isn't just right, but i want to appreciate their time for posting it. Maybe it is just a habit from usual webboard anyway, as the link above i will try not to spam it with thank you message.

Comment: @WesleyMurch Huh! Up votes for sale? Which is the important thing: the question or the (perhaps eventual) "answer"? If one makes a rhetorical "thanks" gesture in consideration of an asyet unknown persona's time spent collaborating, how does that impart anything, for good or for ill, to any resulting answer--except, possibly, in relation to an unseen spirit of collegiality--hopefully without collegiality bias or snobbery? Or, are we exchanging Up's in the anticipation of reciprocal Up's, or to fend off Down's? ...as if Up's were dues in some kind of mutual admiration society? Perish the thought